# Worksheet save failing

Tags: excel, save, vba

I have written a sub that should save worksheet 2 as a csv file with a time stamp in it. I let the user choose the file path with the get path sub, then when the user clicks 'okay' the program fails and says

```
run time error 9, subscript out of range.
```

Can you please help me figure out where/why my program is diong this?

```
Public Sub save()

Dim x As Integer
Dim FName As String

x = MsgBox("Are you sure?!?", vbYesNo, "Send File")
If x <> vbYes Then
GoTo Send_file_end:
End If

FName = get_path & "cambs_uplaoded_trades" & Format(Time, "hh mm ss") & ".csv"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").SaveAs Filename:=FName, FileFormat:=xlCSV
MsgBox "saved "

Send_file_end:
End Sub
```

here is my get path function

```
Function get_path() As String
Dim dlg As Variant

Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
dlg.AllowMultiSelect = False

If dlg.Show <> -1 Then
get_path = ""
Else
get_path = dlg.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Please give us the output of this code in the Immediate/Debug window: `?ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").rows.count` If it gives an error that is the problem.

Comment: I suspect there is no sheet named "sheet2" or "Sheet2".

Comment: @Philip, you say "that is the problem". What problem is that?

Comment: @DougGlancy I mean if he receives an error in the Immediate Window, then that is the cause of the issue, and he'll have to work out the correct name of the worksheet

Comment: I figured out whats going wrong, I can run it the first time i open the excel file but as soon as i use it once it changes sheet2's name to whatever the date is etc, so all i need to do it to chagne the name of the sheet back after i run everything?   I think

Comment: turns out it's not that easy to do. becasuse the name is dependant on time, im not sure how to determine which sheet to change back to 'sheet2'. (i know what sheet, but i dont know how to tell the computer which sheet).  Could I copy the entire sheet to a new workbook and save that workbook?  - if so how?

Answer (score 0):

So i'll show you my solution just in case your interested:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
FName = get_path & "cambs_uplaoded_trades" & Format(Time, "hh mm ss") & ".csv"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").SaveAs Filename:=FName, FileFormat:=xlCSV
MsgBox "saved "
ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2"
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
```

So i activated sheet two before the name was changed, then saved it, then i changed the name of the active workshet back to sheet2.

thanks for you input!